# Floating pane CMV?

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a menubar (Search, Find, Draw, Measure) in my layout. By clicking on the respective buttons I would like to display the widgets.I am using the CMV widgets in my app.Based on the widgets configure in viewer.js file I would like to create dynamic menu and display widgets by clicking on respective buttons. I do not want to load in sidebar panel as this is the default in viewer. Instead sidebar panel I want to load and display by clicking on button on menubar.

How can I do this using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.19?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this project will work for you as is or possibly offers a starting point for you to adapt: https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-calcite-maps

If you do create a menubar using this calcite maps template or some other approach, please share it with the CMV community.

Comment: Hi tmcee,

Thanks for reply.

I tried to open the URL you send above for calcite maps but demo page is not loading properly It just displayed only header and no widgets&map.

Also,I downloaded the zip file from github url calcite maps projects but widgets folder are not included(e.g. Measure, Draw etc..) in the zipped file.

I would like to use cmv app and widgets but with little customization in app.
What I am trying is, I don't want to load the widgets in sidebar panel.

Comment: Instead the sidebar panel I would like to have separate floating panel (Expandable, collapsible, resizable, draggable) for each widgets.

Now, the widgets configured in viewer.js file, create a menu bar with widgets title name or with icons below header and by clicking on the menu it should open the respective floating pane widgets.

Is cmv viewer is custimizable to do above changes ? What changes I 

should do in Controller.js or in floating pane.js ?

It would be a really big help…:)

Thanks.

Comment: @Mayur The order that mixins are loaded was recently updated in the cmv-app repo. I have updated the files and demo in my repo to reflect this revised order.